# Web API Simplest way to pickup a multipart/form-data response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, iis-8, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a problem but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong ?
I want to make the simplest method possible to get this to work I will make it more complex later but currently just want the post method to be hit I don't even care if the code inside is working currently.

only thing I care about is that it sends a OK 200 reply back.

Currently I either get a internal server error 500 response or a 405 method not allowed response depending on if I try to send data or just force the method call with my browser.

have a IOS app that sends the post request below and I have a test PHP script that proved that this worked. Now I want to move it to the server that should be doing the work on a IIS 8. However I'm struggling with just even making the connection currently:

```
POST /api/Image/Upload HTTP/1.1
Host: ServerName
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------Boundary----------35042EC1-790C-4CDD-8E21-66E6B1025C2D
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
filename: DefaultPrefix1.jpg
User-Agent: KameraApp/1 CFNetwork/808.3 Darwin/16.3.0
Content-Length: 5492253
Accept-Language: da-dk
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

---------------Boundary----------35042EC1-790C-4CDD-8E21-66E6B1025C2D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='image'; filename="DefaultPrefix1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg

Image Data
End boundary
```

How I'm trying to pick up the above Multipart/form-data:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Image")]
public class ImageController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Upload")]
        public IHttpActionResult Upload()
        {
            var files= HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

            var aFile = files.Get(0);


            string filename = aFile.FileName;
            string path = @"C:\ImageUploaderService\UploadFolder";
            aFile.SaveAs(path + filename);
            return Ok("Working");
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

changed to the current Method based on the suggestion below

my WebApiConfig looks like this:

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a routing issue. If the intention is to use [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), then make sure that it is [enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enabling-attribute-routing)

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And decorate the target controller accordingly

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Image")]
public class ImageController : ApiController {        
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Upload")] // Matches POST api/Image/Upload
    public IHttpActionResult Upload()
    {
        return Ok("I am working");
    }
}
```

From there you should be able to include your additional functionality.

If you want to read multipart data consider getting it from the request's content.

```
var content = await Request.Content.ReadAsMiltipartAsync();
```

> **only thing I care about is that it sends a OK 200 reply back.**
>
> I want to make the simplest method possible to get this to work I
>   will make it more complex later but **currently just want the post
>   method to be hit** I don't even care if the code inside is working
>   currently.

This answer should address the above. Any further issues should be posted in other questions.

Comment: @Helbo, Did you do exactly what was in my example? because based on your updated question it look like you left your original action content intact. Just follow the example as is in its simplest form first. once it works then you can look into add more complex code.

Comment: you where right @Nikosi I now hit the method when I send the request from my app. Thank you :) now I just need to pick up the data and use it at least now I know how to continue from here :) I will look in to your suggestion of using the Request's content.